# Is it possible to style an Entity Relation Diagram with Mermaid.js like Flowcharts to indicate a difference in entities?

Tags: erd, mermaid

I can't seem to style any elements within my ERD.

Having an entity called `PERSON`, any of the following code results in a syntax error:

```
style PERSON fill:#f9f;
```

or

```
classDef className fill:#f9f; 
class PERSON className;
```

or

```
classDef default fill:#f9f;
```

Looking at the documentation, I should be able to use simple styling:
https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/entityRelationshipDiagram?id=styling

Basically I'm trying to make a high level ERD where I need to mark certain entities to indicate a difference.

Any help or advice would be appreciated. :-)

Comment: Currently this is not possible with the diagram syntax itself. If you have access to the web page CSS [you can apply particular styles to individual items](https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/issues/2673#issuecomment-1493419671). Naturally this wont work if you publish your diagram to a code forge like GitLab or GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Well the [documentation](https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/entityRelationshipDiagram.html#styling) and [issue](https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/issues/2673) were updated 4 months after my answer, thus "Yes" it's possible to style erDiagrams. You have to start with the base style though.

Answer (score -1):

I wasn't in luck either. In flowcharts it seems possible to style and shape the nodes though.
https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/blob/develop/docs/examples.md

Comment: That file does not exist.